# Picard number of Kahler manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a Kahler manifold. How can we define simply the Picard number for the special case where  $M$ is also projective? 
Wikipedia defines it as the rank of the Neron-Severi group.

In particular, when we say that it has Picard number equal to 1, do we just mean that $Pic(M)=\mathbb{Z}$?

I would be appreciate any help/references.

Comment: For a smooth projective variety, the Neron-Severi group is a finitely generated abelian group and its rank is called the Picard number. So, Picard number one would mean that the Picard group is $\mathbb{Z}$ direct sum a finite abelian group.

Comment: @Mohan thank you for your answer. I understand why the NS-group would be  $\mathbb{Z}$ direct sum finite abelian group.  Could you please explain me what is the relationship between the Neron-Severi group and the Picard group?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not say it right. If Picard number is one, it does not mean what I said usually. Neron-Severi group is Picard group modulo all line bundles which are algebraically equivalent to zero. So, Picard group in general will have an abelian variety inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, then the rank of the image $\text{Pic}(X)\to H^2(X,\mathbb R)$ is called the Picard number $\rho(X)$.

Note that if $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold then the Picard number satisfies $$\rho(X)=rk(NS(X))=rk(H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z))$$

By another method also we can define the Picard number.

A line bundle $L$ is numerically trivial if $(L.L') = 0$ for all line bundles $L'$.

The subgroup of all numerically trivial line bundles is denoted $Pic(X)^τ ⊂ Pic(X)$, define

$$Num(X) := Pic(X)/Pic^τ(X).$$

we have the following result for the Picard number ([see page 10](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf) )

$$ρ(X) = rk NS(X) = rk Num(X).$$

We define the Neron-Severi lattice and the associated Neron-Severi space as follows

$$NS(X) := H^{1,1}_{\mathbb R}(X) ∩(H^2(X, \mathbb Z)/{\text\{torsion\}})$$

$$ NS_{\mathbb R}(X) := NS(X) ⊗_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$$

Hence, we have

$$ρ(X) = rank_{\mathbb Z} NS(X) = \dim_{\mathbb R }NS_{\mathbb R}(X)$$

If $f : X −→ Y$ is a proper morphism between normal varieties, then the relative Picard number of $f$ is given by
$$ρ(X/Y ) = ρ(X) - ρ(Y )$$.